# If Xpath doesn't exist, play mp3 - Python

Tags: python, selenium, conditional-statements, alarm

I want to set up an alarm, so when a website changes, it will play a song on my computer.

I'm not sure how to set up the conditional statement for this. Below is what I've written, but obviously it isn't correct. If the element on the website exists, I want to end but if it doesnt exist, (the website has changed) I want the mp3 to play as an alarm.

if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/h1"):

else:

webbrowser.open(r"C:\Users\Julian Layton\Desktop\Andalusia\I Remember.mp3")

I also want this script run every 2 minutes. How can I do this? (Using VS Code)

Comment: Please correctly format your code samples; it makes them easier to read. If you're unsure how to do that there is [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) available. It would also help if you could show us more of your code, and maybe indicate how you've tried to solve things such as the periodic scheduling part. There are a variety of ways to solve that particular problem, and I think there are many examples here on stack overflow.

Comment: One question at a time, please. An XPath problem is one topic. An MP3-playing problem is a _different_ topic. Scheduling Python code to run on a timer is a _third_ topic. There's no reason to ask a single question that combines them, unless you have a specific technical issue that only comes up when combining _those precise things_.

Comment: Keeping your questions separate also makes it more likely that you'll be successful at finding already-answered duplicates (for those smaller individual questions) in the knowledgebase already -- and if you're successful at that, then some aspects of this question won't need to be asked at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if not driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/h1"):
    webbrowser.open(r"C:\Users\Julian Layton\Desktop\Andalusia\I Remember.mp3")
```

`find_elements` method returns a list of web elements.
In case no elements found it returns an empty list interpreted as False by Python. This will involve your command.
In order to run this every 2 minutes you can put this in loop with 2 minutes delay

```
while True:
    if not driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/h1"):
        webbrowser.open(r"C:\Users\Julian Layton\Desktop\Andalusia\I Remember.mp3")
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(120)
```

here I added a 2 minutes sleep between iterations and a `break` to stop this in case of calling the music file. Not sure what exactly logic you are looking for, this seems to me to be matching your question.

Comment: I would argue that this answers multiple questions, in the sense referred to by the fourth bullet point of the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If we have a new question for every _permutation_ of questions someone might ask at the same time, we lose the value of having highly-curated, canonical questions (which lots of people have had eyes on, added answers to, commented on, reviewed, improved, added additional/variant answers to, etc. over time).

Comment: I agree with you, Charles. I see the asker is a beginner, so I preferred to help his rather than closing this not-so-perfectly-asked question as "need more focus".